# How to change webcam format in JavaCV?

Tags: java, format, webcam, javacv

I finally got JavaCV working with my webcam but I can't find a way to change the output format of the image grabbed.

I have a HP HD (720p) fixed webcam in my HP notebook. The only resolution I get is 640x480. I tried using all available subclasses of FrameGrabber.

I am using this simple code:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class Webcam {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FrameGrabber grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
        grabber.start();

        IplImage grabbedImage = grabber.grab();

        CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Some Title", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma() / grabber.getGamma());

        while (frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = grabber.grab()) != null) {
            frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
        }

        frame.dispose();
        grabber.stop();
    }

}
```

Am I missing something or is there another way to capture image from a webcam using JavaCV?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another way to capture from webcam and also set some properties like preferred width and height.

This code works for me:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.CvCapture;

public class Webcam {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CvCapture capture = opencv_highgui.cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

        opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720);
        opencv_highgui.cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, opencv_highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);

        IplImage grabbedImage = opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture);

        CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Webcam");

        while (frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = opencv_highgui.cvQueryFrame(capture)) != null) {
            frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
        }

        frame.dispose();
        opencv_highgui.cvReleaseCapture(capture);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps somebody with same problem.

Comment: Calling `grabber.setImageWidth()` and `setImageHeight()` before `start()` should also do what you need.

Comment: You're right Samuel, I somehow missed that or I've put it after `start()`.

Comment: @BranislavKuliha when I set my Logitech C910 to it's native 5MP, I find that the FrameGrabber's FPS drops quite a bit when compared to 640x480 (buttery smooth). Is this more my system's available resources than anything else? I want to use this as an enterprise solution, and if I just need to set up a very powerful computer, so be it!

Comment: @Davek804: I don't your webcam supports 5MP capture at that high fps rate. Check [link](http://www.crazysales.com.au/logitech-c910-hd-pro-10-megapixel-webcam.html?utm_campaign=Web%20Cameras&utm_term=Logitech%20C910%20HD%20Pro%2010%20Megapixel%20Webcam%20Full%20HD%201080p%20Recording&utm_source=myshopping&utm_medium=cpc&aid=3) to see the full specs and system requirements. I think your fps should be smooth at max 1080p that is 2MP capture.